# Snowflake id value not preserved when passing to webapi

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly

I had develop blazorWASM aplication.

In this appllication I want to generate unique order id thats why I had choose snowflakeid to avoid duplicate orders

I had used snowflakeid nuget package as below procedure
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SnowflakeIDGenerator

I had generate the snowflakeid using  machineid and customepoch. snowflakid type is long

that snowflakeid want to maintain in db and I had passed the snowflakeid through api using serialization process at the time snowflakeid value changed  like

snowflakeid original value: 526688986857484300

snowflakeid changed value:526688986857484304

For suppose before seralization If i changed the type to string at the time also snowflakeid changed

I know Issue happened If i do change the long to string thats why I had ignore type conversion. I know largeinter numbers or snowflake id changed when conversion thats why i had ignored but when seralization also issue happened

```
    public async Task<Orders> Updateorder(Orders order, IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        var getorder = new Orders();


        try
        {
            var client = clientFactory.CreateClient("WebAPI");
            var updaterequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "api/Orders/UpdateOrder");
            POSOrderRequest request = new POSOrderRequest();
            request.Baseobject=order;
            string serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
            StringContent content = new StringContent(serializedData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync(updaterequest.RequestUri, content);
         
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var updatereponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;


                UpdateOrderapireposne apires = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UpdateOrderapireposne>(updatereponse);


                getorder = apires.BaseObject;


            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {


        }


        return getorder;
    }
```

I want to maintain Snowflake id value preserved when passing to  webapi

Please help me. Thank you.

I want to maintain Snowflake id value preserved when passing to  webapi

Comment: Hi - what has this question got to do with the Snowflake cloud DBMS that you’ve tagged it with?

Comment: No.snowflake I'd passing to web api

Comment: Snowflake id value not preserved when passing to webapi